# Not able to establish connection after hosting web application on IIS, using SQL LocalDB

Tags: c#, .net, localdb

Not able to establish a connection after hosting a web application on IIS using SQL local DB. Security permissions provided to IIS user in the SQL and changed Identity to "Local System" in IIS>Applicationpool>ProcessModel

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="AppEntities" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-94RO4JF\LOCALDB#D17FD0BA;Initial Catalog=Alarms;User Id=;Password=;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="AppEntities" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\Alarms;Initial Catalog=Alarms;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Showing Following Error:
**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.**